# Wrap two HTML elements in DIV with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to wrap two elements around a div, but my code is not working as expected. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group requiredField">
  <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
  <span class="help">help text</span>
</div>
```

Here is what I want my HTML to look like:

```
<div class="form-group requiredField">
  <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
    <span class="help">help text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am trying to wrap the `input` and `span` tags in a `<div class="col-sm-9">`. I have tried using the following jQuery snippets but to no avail:

```
//This only wraps the span
$("#form-group input").next().wrap('<div class="col-sm-9">');
```

I have also tried this:

```
//This only wraps the input
$("#form-group input").wrap('<div class="col-sm-9">');
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: most of the answers, aside from your own, will *not* work with multiple `form-group`s.

Your aim appears to wrap all child elements, except the *label*, into a child div. If so a simple approach is literally to exclude the label with `:not` and then `wrapAll`:

```
$('.form-group').each(function(){
    $(':not(label)', this).wrapAll('<div class="col-sm-9"></div>');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6by51ytL/1/

Note: should you ever have deeper nested children in your `form-group`, add the immediate child selector (`>`):

```
$('.form-group').each(function(){
    $('>:not(label)', this).wrapAll('<div class="col-sm-9"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select both the elements using multiple selector then

```
$(".form-group").find('input, span').wrapAll('<div class="col-sm-9">');
//class selector is used for `form-group`
```

```js
$(".form-group").find('input, span').wrapAll('<div class="col-sm-9">');
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="form-group requiredField">
  <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required="" style="width:50%;">
  <span class="help">help text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan still the multiple selector was wrong... used descendant selector instead

Answer (score 0):

Try below code use

Use jQuery [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) and [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

HTML

```
<div class="form-group requiredField">
  <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
  <span class="help">help text</span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.control-label').nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="col-sm-9" />');
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/e05tf7pj/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This code works for me:

```
$('.form-group input').each(function () {
    $(this).next('span.help').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="col-sm-9">');
          });
```

Comment: This answer works, but the selector is "fragile" (it will not cope with HTML changes). Have added another option for you that also supports multiple `form-group`s